# Start new node.js project - What is the equivalent of angular-seed for node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm looking for a seed project to start angular.js and node.js project.

I ran into few samples:

https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed

https://github.com/pilwon/ultimate-seed

http://mean.io/

Does someone has experience with one of them? what do you recommend?

Answer (score -1):

If you have node and npm installed, you can use yeoman to scaffold out an angular web app.

```
mkdir webapp && cd webapp
npm init
npm install yeoman --save-dev
npm install generator-webapp --save-dev
npm install generator-angular --save-dev

yo angular
```

Comment: i'm looking for a seed project? what do you offer ?